# ionic lib 1.1.0 causing $injector error

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have just updated the ionic library to `1.1.0` and I am now seeing the below error.

`Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$forceReflowProvider <- $$forceReflow <- $$animateQueue <- $animate <- $compile <- $ionicTemplateLoader <- $ionicPopup <- $$animateQueue
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/unpr?p0=%24%24forceReflowProvid…0%24ionicTemplateLoader%20%3C-%20%24ionicPopup%20%3C-%20%24%24animateQueue`

[image]

I am unable to find which file in my library is causeing this error.

Comment: I think you are having conflict of version with `animation.js` & `angular.js` you need to update

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @pankaj Parkar I was giving incorrect answer to bower conflicts when updating

```
Unable to find a suitable version for angular-animate, please choose one:
    1) angular-animate#1.3.13 which resolved to 1.3.13 and is required by ionic#1.0.1
    2) angular-animate#1.4.3 which resolved to 1.4.3 and is required by ionic#1.1.0
    3) angular-animate#~1.4.4 which resolved to 1.4.7 and is required by Rehab_Guru

Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json

? Answer 2

Unable to find a suitable version for angular-sanitize, please choose one:
    1) angular-sanitize#1.3.13 which resolved to 1.3.13 and is required by ionic#1.0.1
    2) angular-sanitize#1.4.3 which resolved to 1.4.3 and is required by ionic#1.1.0

Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json

? Answer 2
bower install       ionic#1.1.0
```